# Writing a handlebars helper in Ember

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

In my app I am trying to write a custom handlebars helper. My helper looks like this

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('__', function(person) {
   console.log(person);
   return person.get('name');
}, 'name');
```

I have a person class like this

```
App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  name : 'moshin'
});
```

In my hbs file I am trying and doing this

```
{{__ person}}
```

But it outputs undefined. Can anybody explains how to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Is person actually defined in your template?  Your logic there is spot on.  I'm guessing maybe you've failed to create an instance of person, and maybe you aren't referencing it in the template correctly.  Here's an example of your code, working...

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fuwahemi/1/edit

Comment: I didn't added this bit App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Person.create();
  }
});

Comment: I'd read through the entire router/route section of the ember guides, but particularly this portion, http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/